# What is the largest $n$ for which $n+5$ divides $n^5+5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The largest $n$ for which $n+5$ divides $n^5+5$ is? $n$ being a natural number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice $(n+5)$ divides $n^5+5^5$(because $a+b$ always divides $a^n+b^n$ for odd $n$). So $n+5$ divides $n^5+5$ if and only if It divides $(n^5+5^5)-(n^5+5)=5^5-5=3120$.

The máximum is obtained by taking $n+5=3120$.

Comment: can you elaborate please:)

Comment: I got the answer though.it is 3115.

Comment: I did it as follows: (n^5)+5=(n+5-5)^5+5. and then using binomial expansion you can come to the answer.

Comment: Elaborated ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: typo mate, its gotta be if and only if divides...

Comment: Why you wrote, "So n+5 divides $n^5+5$ if and only if It divides $(n^5+5^5)−(n^5+5)=5^5−5=3120$" ?